# Nested jQuery ajax calls wont work in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I have a script that calls jQuery ajax functions nested in each other - the script works in Chrome and IE9, is there a reason why it doesn't want to work in Firefox?

The code is posted below:

```
$.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", 
                cache: false, 
                url: "addwelder.php", 
                data: "mywelderid="+$welderid,
                success: function()
                {
                    $.ajax({ 
                        type: "GET", 
                        cache: false, 
                        url: "loadwelder.php", 
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            $("#mywelders:last-child").append("<option value=" + data[0].toString() + ">" + data[1].toString() + "</option>");
                            $("#mywelders option:last").attr("selected","selected");
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, exc)
                        {
                            alert(xhr.status);
                            alert(exc);
                        }

                    });
                },
                error: function(xhr, exc)
                {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(exc);
                }

            });
```

Comment: Just to be sure : you test in the same conditions ? You don't happen to test opening the file in `file://` on Firefox ?

Comment: Check a list of actual XHR requests in Firebug->Network. And see if there are any errors.

Comment: Did the ajax call starts at least ? Take a look with firebug extension for firefox.

Comment: what do you mean "*doesn't work*". Do the alerts get executed (*if so which one*)?

Comment: Why are you making the outer call? You aren't using any data from it

Comment: running it off the localhost;

Comment: the outer call is executed to store some data in the database - it works, the inner statement (that doesn't execute) is to retrieve primary key indexes